# How long does it take for an alpha particle to pick up electrons from its environment?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, radiation

An alpha particle that has been emitted has an electric charge of 2e, so electrons should be attracted to it. How long does this take? What does it depend on?

Comment: Making a comment because I'm not 100% certain, but I'd imagine this depends on environment and the alpha particle energy. The fact that it happens quickly when there are a lot of neutral atoms around, though, probably contributes to their very low penetration depth. https://emilms.fema.gov/IS3/FEMA_IS/is03/REM0202100.htm

Comment: @Sean  So whenever it loses that charge, it no longer has the energy to travel further?

Comment: I hesitate to comment, because I'm not an expert on this sub-topic. I will say, though, that the charge makes it interact with the matter around it strongly, causing it to quickly dump it's energy. I'm not sure at what point the electrons tend to get picked up during this process.

Comment: Alpha particles have MeV energies. They will strip electrons off air molecules, then lose them again in the next interaction, making 10-eV excitations on their way.

Comment: @Pieter is correct - the ion energy has to drop pretty low before it will start having a good change of becoming (and staying) neutral. At MeV energies it is quite easy to strip the electrons in a short distance of well-below-atomospheric pressure (as used in many tandem accelerators).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend on the density of neutral matter it meets on the way. This is true for all charged particles in matter.In less dense matter like cloud chambers and bubble chambers the tracks of ions can be seen, [as in this video with alpha particles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noP7HT-Uins) in a cloud chamber. The alphas become neutral at the end of the track, where they stop and can grab electrons from the atoms in the chamber.  They have lost most of their energy in ionizing the neutral atoms of the chamber. It is very  fast, microseconds.