# Forming of helium in radioactive decay

Tags: electrons, nuclear-physics, radiation, radioactivity, inert-gases

I have just came across a question, where 1mole of Uranium (238 92) gets converted to Pb(206 82) now after balancing we get that during this decay in presence of air, 8 alpha particles and 6 beta particles are released, my question is how many moles of helium is formed,what my logic is alpha particle will combine with beta particle and one alpha particle would need 2 beta particle to form helium, so according to that 3 moles of helium should be form but the answer is given as 8 which is = no. Of alpha particles, why so?

Comment: Hi. The punctuation on this question is *barely readable*.

Comment: Consider what happens to the electrons of an atom when its nucleus emits an alpha particle.

Answer (score 4):

The beta particles (electrons) have nothing to do with how much helium is formed. Amount of helium = amount of helium nuclei = amount of alpha particles. They are ions but that doesn't matter. They will grab electrons from whatever they come into contact with and become neutral that way.

Answer (score 1):

The question is obviously conflating "alpha particles" and "helium atoms".   This isn't a bad approximation, though, because most alpha particles will pick up extra electrons readily from their environment unless they're traveling through a pretty hard vacuum.

It is conceivable that the electrons picked up by the alpha particles could be one of the electrons emitted as a beta particle in the decay chain.  But for this to be at all likely, you would need some other matter in the way to slow down the ejected radiation anyhow;  otherwise the alphas and betas would likely zip off in different directions at different speeds and never encounter each other.  And if you do have matter around to slow down the alphas and betas, the alpha particles would probably be more likely to steal an electron from the surrounding matter than to encounter a free electron from a prior decay.

Here are some related questions that explore this formation a bit further:

- [Do alpha particles attract electrons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/511456/do-alpha-particles-attract-electrons)
- [How do alpha particles emit the helium spectrum without electrons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/419637/how-do-alpha-particles-emit-the-heleum-spectrum-without-electrons)  (Short answer:  they don't)
- [How long does it take for an alpha particles to pick up electrons from its environment?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/378962/how-long-does-it-take-for-an-alpha-particle-to-pick-up-electrons-from-its-enviro)

Comment: Also, for the benefit of the OP, when converting from U to Pb, some electrons will be lost also (10) as Pb has less protons than U. The question relates to radioactive decay, which is nuclear physics. However, nuclei are not usually in their "naked" form, unless the temperature is high enough. At room temperature, they are surrounded by electrons, one for each proton.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - I agree that an alpha particle is a helium nucleus, but really the terms should be conflated since, well, they are the same (plus or minus a few electrons). Some distinctions are sub-field dependent, but if I ionize helium and send it down a beamline to do Rutherford Backscattering Spectrometry, I'm doing alpha scattering...

Comment: Total electrons will not be lost in the system, charge will be preserved.  Neutral uranium has more protons/electrons than lead, but these will be balanced by the protons/electrons in the final helium atom.